# Import music file to jar file

Tags: java, audio, netbeans, jar, javasound

I have created a java project which has some sound effects. Later when I exported it into jar file. Audio files were not exported, so no audio clips were played.

Can this issue be solved?

Comment: Try adding some code.

Comment: Need some more details to be able to troubleshoot this...

Comment: I need to know the packaging of java project.for the same reason i dont think posting code is relevent here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a fat `.jar` archive with all of your resources. If you are using maven or gradle, there are plugins for this. If you don't you can also find plugins depending on your IDE.

Comment: I am using neatbeans IDE. Is there any extra plugins

Comment: Just tip it on Google, I find this tutorial, look if this is fitting your needs https://dzone.com/articles/how-build-fat-jar-using

Comment: i just copied my sound tracks to the folder were the jar files were exported.it now works